# Windows 7 or Windows 8?

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-8

I really can't decide as to which OS should I choose to be my final OS. I can't afford to keep it dual booted as I really want to stick on to ONLY one.

On one side, Windows 7 is super robust and I use nowadays to only play games and on the other side, I need Windows 8 (primarily) as I develop Windows 8 apps. Asus, who's laptop I own, has released updated drivers for Windows 8. Games run fine on Windows 8 too. I am yet to encounter a 'proper' problem on Windows 8, but I still feel Windows 8 to be sort-of like a beta build. Do you think it is wise ditching anyone of the OSes altogether, and whatever may be your answer, why?

Comment: This is too open and it likely to be closed. However, since you it sounds like you need Windows 8 to develop Apps and you didn't say any reason you need windows 7, why would you not go with Windows 8?

Comment: I was afraid of that. I use Win7 to play games and a few softwares work well on Win7 rather than Win8. I believe that desktop softwares haven't been optimized yet for Win8. I feel that I'm operating a beta when using Windows 8 - it's unknown whether something will work or not but on Win7, I can be sure that it will definitely work (and most of the times it does).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stay at Windows 7 and run Windows 8 inside a VM (VMware) to develop the apps there with VS2012.

Comment: How will the performance be? I'm running a Core i7 3610QM, 8GB RAM, and 2 GB graphic card? Will the performance be laggy or choppy? When using VMWare, will the experience be like I'm operating Win8 'as is'?

Comment: VMware has a good experience and is fast. I'm also using it to run Vs2012 in Windows 8.